# Change the color of Zoom control Google map 3

Tags: google-maps-api-3

i'm looking for some info about Google Map V3. I want change the color of the zoom control , i want it red...

How can i change the color simply ?

Thank you for response !

Answer (score 3):

They're images, so you can't simply "change" the color. What you can do, however, is create a map WITHOUT the zoom controls and then just use the API and your own DOM elements as zoom controls.

This will give you a very rough idea:

```
var map = new google.maps.Map();
//zoom out
map.setZoom(map.getZoom()-1);
//zoom in
map.setZoom(map.getZoom()+1);
```